# Responsive Web Design + SCSS site organization

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, sass

For me `HTML` + `CSS` is quite complex. `HTML` + `CSS` + `@media` is nightmare. Now my `HTML` + `CCS` looks like spagetti. Pls help me with questions:

1. How should I organize my `SCSS` includes: by function (header/footer)
   or by dimension (0_480)?
2. How should I use @media limits:

   - max-width only: 0-420, 0-870, no limit
   - min-width + max-width: 0-420, 421-870, 871+
   - min-width only: 870+, 420+, 0+

Comment: I think you’ve really got two separate questions here, so you should probably ask them separately.

Comment: Basing your media queries on px is not a very good idea:  http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw/

Answer (score 1):

To test site for Adaptability can be easily and quickly!
http://plastilin5.com/tools/

Answer (score 0):

here's a good example (check in the lower part of the site)

http://m.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/

you can place all your stylesheet imports in the header.

Answer (score 0):

1. Here is what I do:

   - write CSS for maximum size only
   - at the end of the CSS file (or as @import if the project is to big) add "@media screen and (max-width: 1700px)" and write all the changes for that resolution
   - repeat previous step for every needed resolution

The main reason I think this is the best approach is that for the smaller screens you can (and most probably will) decide not to show some of the elements, and you'll be able to do that by simply adding display:none; to those elements on the first (biggest) resolution they are to be hidden on. While when you're building your CSS the other way around, adding elements becomes a bit harder to follow.

Answer (score 0):

On how to use `@media` max and min widths, some developers would argue strongly for “mobile first”, e.g. focus on styles for small screens first, and then override those styles for larger screens.

- http://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/blog/about/320_and_up/

I think that would match most closely with your “max-width only: 0-420, 0-870, no limit” option.

Answer (score 0):

Sass has what they call "media query bubbling", which means that no matter what nesting level your media queries are placed at, they will bubble up to the top.  This is both a good thing and a bad thing if you aren't using it responsibly (good that you can keep your media queries grouped with related styles, bad if used excessively since you end up with 100s of media queries all over the place).

What I've found that works for my workflow is to group together media queries as much as possible with the block of content that its for.  Each major block of styles is broken up into its own file (master layout, image gallery, clients, etc), and each file will have as few numbers of media queries as possible (typically only 1 or 2, 3 or more for more complex blocks).

```
$x-small-device: 25em; // smallest
$small-device: 35em; // larger mobile
$medium-device: 55em; // tablet or really small desktop

.clients {
    // no matter what resolution, these styles are always applied

    @media (min-width: $small-device) {
        // have our clients display in a 2-col layout
    }

    @media (min-width: $medium-device) {
        // have our clients display in a 3-col layout
    }
}
```

If you try to break it up based on the width of the device you're targeting, it is more difficult to find where the styles are located when it comes time to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all I think that you should read more about CSS architecture. The first question is kinda complex and involves different concepts. I'll suggest to check [OOCSS](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/12/12/an-introduction-to-object-oriented-css-oocss/), [SMACSS](http://smacss.com/) or [Atomic design](http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/post/atomic-web-design/). There are some really great ideas. What I usually do is to use a mixture between all those things. I guess that you will find what it fits in your project.
Media queries should not be based on the devices or on some popular resolutions. You should set your break points based on the content that you have. Try to follow the Mobile First concept and see where the content needs updating. Very often the different break points are related to different parts of your site. I mean one media query may refer only the header of the application. Another only the footer and so on. I'll also suggest to use media queries bubbling. I.e. to place those parts inside the container that you want to change, not in a separate file or at the end of the current one.